After enabled LWS in sandbox windows.location.hostname is returning null
I am unable fetch the base url using window.location.hostname due to LWS being enabled in the sandbox. If LWS disabled it workings fine. Any solution would be much appreciated.
alert(window.location.hostname);
alert is showing null.

Lightning Web Security on or off, shouldn't have a problem with getting the location of the window. It should work fine and fetch the base url in both the cases.
In case you are referring to window.postMessage() for an iframe use case you might run into issues of getting the target origin. Kindly clarify your use case or provide detailed info.
